# Cocoapods issue in Mojave OS

Tags: ios, cocoapods, macos-mojave

I'm Unable to install pods in my iOS project after updating Mac OS to Mojave. I am getting the following error. (Note: I have already updated my Cocoapods to the latest version).

````
### Podfile

```ruby
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'MojavePodTest' do
  # Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  pod 'Alamofire', '~> 4.5'
end
```

### Error

```
Errno::ENOTEMPTY - Directory not empty @ dir_s_rmdir - /Users/Name/Library/Caches/CocoaPods/Pods
````

Comment: you can delete all data in your the cache directory and try again

Comment: Share your podfile , might be there is a issue on the same

Comment: @Myaaoonn My pod file content 

`# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project`
`# platform :ios, '9.0'`

`target 'MojavePodTest' do`
  `# Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks`
  `use_frameworks!`

  `pod 'Alamofire', '~> 4.5'`
`end`

Comment: @QuocNguyen Tried to clear the cache using following command
`pod cache clean --all`
But no luck.. :(

Comment: Can you share the cocoapods version number?

Comment: @Kamran Cocoapods Version number: 1.5.3

Comment: @Rameez Updating to `1.6.xxxx beta` should fix the issue (`sudo gem install cocoapods --pre`).

Comment: Thank you @Kamran 
It worked :)

Answer (score 0):

After "end" keyword, you have some quote remains. Please check or copy paste the below ones.

```
    # Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'Workmate' do
  # Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!


pod 'Alamofire', '~> 4.5'

  # Pods for Workmate

end
```

If still you have issues, then create a new podfile and add your "Alamofire"

Comment: I verified the pod file and there is no quote ... And also created new pod file issue still exist.

Comment: can you clear your derived data once and fresh install your app.